# Is there is any way to serve my php app from computer to whole internet?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am a PHP developing a PHP telegram bot in my VPS. Whenever I have to change something in code I have to first open the file and then edit it then reload the server to see the effect of the changes it's a lot to do is there is any simple way?

I can not use localhost of my computer here because telegram API send me updates through post request every time a user uses my bot, therefore telegram can not send it to HTTP:localhost:3000

I also tried polling (checking telegram API every second for updates) but telegram throw me a timeout error that way.

so if you have any idea please share with us

Comment: Why is that a lot of effort? You would be doing the exact same process on your localhost - open the file, edit it, open the page to test it. ( I assume the latter is what you mean by "reload the server" - you don't need to reboot your server just to change a PHP file)

Comment: if your local machine have a public ip you can set telegram to use that ip instead, if not there is way to make VPN with your VPS and redirect traffic to your local machine, for example https://www.tinc-vpn.org/ can do that

Answer (score 0):

To make your IP visible to the internet you should use a technique called [Port Forwarding](https://portforward.com/).

Because you haven't mentioned what kind of router you use to connect to the internet I'm not able to write any examples on this.

I suggest you stick to `getUpdates` method (which is long polling as you said).  To make sure you have access to telegram bot api server, open your browser and visit this link (**Replace your bot token in the link**):

[https://api.telegram.org/bot[YOUR_BOT_TOKEN]/getUpdates](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BYOUR_BOT_TOKEN%5D/getUpdates)

Replace `[YOUR_BOT_TOKEN]` with your own token. If it works and doesn't give you a timeout error, that means you're using a wrong link in your script or the library you're using has issues.